# Create twisted lines around the surface of a waterdrop

Tags: bezier-curves, transparency, lines

I want to create a waterdrop where thin lines are wrapped around the object.
To be more precise: I just want to see the fine thin lines twisted around the object.

How would you do this?
Create them via curves?

[image: Something like this but with much more lines]

[image]

Comment: are you talking about the first image or second image?

Comment: ...and is the "object" a sphere? or any object?

Comment: I want the lines to be similar as you can see in the second image, the image of the drop is the best image I have found what comes close enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm surprised that both Chris and Robin Betts provided an interesting answer, but neither of them accurately addressed the actual question ;-)
>
> Hence now the answer to your question (Based on Robin Betts ingenious method of creating the spiral!).

[image]

[image]

1. First create a spiral according to your wishes (if not already done).
2. Then multiply that spiral on a point or circle and randomly rotate the instances until you like the result.
3. Since we are dealing with curves here, you can then use the node `Trim Curve` to make only parts of it visible.
4. If you like it (I like it anyway) you can animate the trim in a timed way combined with random values and other inputs.

[image]

PS: If you also use the `Random Value` node for scaling, you can vary the size of the individual curves again during instantiation.

Comment: I didn't read this into the OP.. but this is a very nice twist :D And you're much better at untangling trees than me...

Comment: @RobinBetts: Looks like we both aren't the best readers... :D

Comment: Thanks, gents! Really helpful and very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5):

if you mean the second picture, you could use geometry nodes with this node setup:

[image]

So every edge will be checked whether the z values are not the same, by this all edges which are vertically will be deleted.

so you get this:

[image]

then i delete random edges by a noise texture with a decent scale:

[image]

ok, finally i made it to build spirals mathematically...

here is the final node tree:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: and if he means the first one...

Comment: well...he is talking of "fine lines"....first pic doesn't look for me like fine line... ;)

Comment: Also, you can add something to your answer: if he wants the whole version (without the edges/vertices being deleted) it can be twisted using a "simple deform" (it's simple but I still wonder why it's called "simple" deform) modifier on the Z-Axis

Comment: Yeah you're right

Comment: yeah, you are right...i will add...just a moment

Answer (score 3):

This group will 'Spiralize' a given profile curve, along its local Z..

[image]

..setting the Z of a created unit spiral to the Z sampled from the profile, and scaling it in XY by the sampled XY length. For convenience, the modifier lets you adjust the spiral using the modified profile curve, and remove it from the geometry when done.

[image]

[image]